# Redirecting to action -- action body not running

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with an Index method that builds the model and passes it to the view.  Leaving aside the wisdom of that design, it looks like this:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
      {
        IEnumerable<CustomViewModelObject> myListOfCustomViewModelObjects = await BuildListOfCustomViewModelObjectsAsync();
        return View(myListOfCustomViewModelObjects);
      }
```

It works fine, even if the IEnumerable is empty.

However, I have a *different* method which appends to that list and I am finding that a null is being passed into my view (where myListOfCustomViewModelObjects should be), breaking the functionality.  That method looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddSelf(AddSelfViewModel model)
      {
        //I'm trimming the part where this data is actually added
        await DoWork();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
```

The saving part works fine, but the redirect leads to null being passed and so the view throws an exception.  If I manually navigate to the index again there's no problem.

What's going on?  How can I fix it?

**edit**:  Since there's a lot of focus on the comments on the order in which things get done, I feel compelled to point out the that the method in the Index action runs a query finding entities owned by the current user, then selects them into an IEnumerable of the ViewModel and feeds that to the view.  AddSelf is adding a new entity which would be owned by the user.  However, my problem is *not* that the IEnumerable is empty, or that it does not include the newly added entity.  In fact, the results are the same (both in the way it works when I go direct to Index and doesn't work in the redirect) whether there are entities that match the conditions to start with or not.

**another edit:** I've copied the body of the Index action into the AddSelf action (with the modification of explicitly naming the view I want it to return since it no longer matches the action) and it works.  Of course, this means I'm duplicating the same code in multiple places, so I'd still like to know what's going on.

Comment: Could it be because you are loosing HTTP Context when using async pattern? Have you tried run second method synchronously?

Comment: `RedirectToAction` simply sends a 302 Redirect to the browser which would result in a standard GET request to the `Index` action.  I suspect that your work is actually not finished by the time the redirect is processed and thus there is no data yet to get. Issuing a GET manually likely allows enough time to pass so that the data has been generated and thus it works. There isn't enough code here to tell you why.

Comment: Well, I'm awaiting a call to SaveChangesAsync with my class inheriting from DbContext.  But it really shouldn't matter; if there are no entities in the collection it should just pass an empty IEnumerable, but it doesn't do that; it's getting a null object (but only from the AddSelf action).  Accessing the Index page before I have any entities works fine.

Comment: I've edited this sample code to make it clearer that I'm dealing with an IEnumerable since var obscured that.

Comment: This link might help: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

Comment: Yes, thanks, but looking at the actual problem, I can't see the relevance of the order in which async tasks are performed.

Comment: Another thought, how long does BuildListOfCustomViewModelObjectsAsync() take, is it possible that it's timing out? Async controller methods have a different default script timeout.

Comment: Not long at all.  Less than a second, I think.